# Sorting an input array of objects in C++

Tags: c++, vector, sorting

I have a base class `Shape`, and other derived classes `Circle`, `Square` and `Triangle`. I created vector of three base-class pointers.

```
vector < Shape * > shapes( 3 );
shapes[ 0 ] = &C1; //Circle C1;
shapes[ 1 ] = &S1; //Square S1;
shapes[ 2 ] = &T1; //Triangle T1;
```

After that, I used a `loop` to call `virtualViaPointer()` that would call the virtual function `draw()`

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < shapes.size(); ++i) {
    cout << endl;
    virtualViaPointer( shapes[ i ] );
}

void virtualViaPointer(const Shape * const baseClassPtr)
{
baseClassPtr->draw();
}
```

Each derived class has a function `getArea()` that calculates the area of each shape and returns the result.

Now, I want to sort the areas by using the `vector` above, and calling `getArea()` functions. How can I do that?
For example, my sort function should be like this `sortShape(Array, numShape)`, where `Array` is an array of `Shape` pointers pointing to the created shapes.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a suitable comparison function:

```
bool compareArea(const Shape* lhs, const Shape* rhs){
  return lhs->getArea() < rhs->getArea();
}

...

std::sort(shapes.begin(), shapes.end(), compareArea);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the sort algorithms with a user-defined sorting criterion, e.g.

```
std::sort(shapes.begin(), shapes.end(), [](Shape * lhs, Shape * rhs)
{
  return lhs->getArea() < rhs->getArea();
});
```

Comment: This is cool but please also note that it requires a modern compiler.

Comment: It would be good to state that using a lambda function is only supported C++11.